# 2 controllers in One app : $Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have 2 controllers in one app.

Each controller is linked to a form.
 In the first controller I can get the value from the form but in the second I can't and I'm using ng-model with dot `user.name` and it's nearly the same code in both of controllers and forms.

Could it be a `$scope` problem ?

1. first controller (working):

   ```
   customModule2.controller('ProjectController',function ($state, $stateParams, $location, $log,$http, $scope, projectFactory , appSettings) {
   $scope.project = {};
   $scope.setProject = function () {
   if($scope.ProjectForm.$valid) {
       projectFactory.addProject($scope.project)
           .success(function (data) {
               $scope.addMessage = data;
               console.log('here' + $scope.project.name);
           })
           .error(function (data, status) {
               $scope.addMessage = "Erreur lors de l'ajout : " + data + ' ' + status;
               console.log('here');
               $log.log(data.error + '' + status);
           });
       $scope.showMessage = true;
       $scope.ProjectForm.$setPristine();
   }
   };
   ```

2.Second controller :

```
customModule2.controller('UserController',function ($state, $stateParams, $location, $log,$http, $scope, userFactory , appSettings) {

 $scope.user = {};
 $scope.setUser = function () {
if($scope.UserForm.$valid) {
    userFactory.addUser($scope.user)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log("controller set : " + this.user.firstname);
            $scope.addMessage = data;
            $log.log('');

        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            console.log("user firstname : " + $scope.user.firstname);
         });
    $scope.UserForm.$setPristine();
}
};
)};
```

In View side, I can see the user value getting filled but I get null in the console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

Form for first controller :

```
 <form name="ProjectForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="setProject()" >
```

```
   <button id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showMessage = 'false'" ng-disabled="ProjectForm.$invalid">Save</button>
```

Form for Second controller :

```
 <form name="UserForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="setUser()" >
```

```
   <button id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showMessage = 'false'" ng-disabled="UserForm.$invalid">Save</button>
```

To set a controller for every View I'm using `angular-ui-router`library like this :

```
    var addProjectState = {
    name: 'addProject',
    url: '/addProject',
    params: {
        projectId: null
    },
    controller : 'ProjectController',
    templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/transtu/Project/add'
};

    var addUserState = {
    name: 'addUser',
    url: '/addUser',
    params: {
        userId: null
    },
    controller : 'UserController',
    templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/transtu/User/add'
};
```

Comment: show your html alongside how you use your controller. and do you not get the value for `$scope.UserForm.$valid`?

Comment: I've updated my post, yeah I'm getting value from it.

Comment: nothing obvious showing...create a plunker that replicates problem

Comment: what does `$scope.UserForm` return?

Comment: actually how do I check if there's a value from it ?

Comment: console.log it and see what's there

Comment: oh I did that and nothing shows

Comment: check this : https://plnkr.co/edit/PV1q9z?p=preview

Comment: too many broken dependencies and missing script tags to test in that demo. I started adding scripts but breaks due to dependencies